is it possible to plot bar charts over a 3D line in plotly?
Can we make plot something like this in plotly using bar chart or something else?
Green line is the 3D lines and the values are plotted over this green line.
3D line can be easily plotted in plotly but showing another set of values over this 3D lines is challenge.
enter image description here

Does this answer your question? How to plot 3D Bar chart/ Pie Chart/ Donut using Plotly

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
